# Error while executing py manage py migrate

Tags: python, mongodb, visual-studio

im having an error while running py manage .py migrate

```
PS C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Python\crudproject> py manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 113, in load_backend
    return import_module("%s.base" % backend_name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\djongo\base.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .operations import DatabaseOperations
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\djongo\operations.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pytz
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytz'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
```

please see how the error could be solved

Comment: `pytz` is a third-party library.  Did you install it?

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of Django this error is common, as the use of this third-party library is being deprecated, but you can still install it with `pip install pytz` or read the documentation to understand better

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/releases/4.0/#zoneinfo-default-timezone-implementation